# I found error "call to a member function setData() on a non-object in controllers\IndexController.php on line 11"

Tags: magento-1.8

**app\code\local\Svi\Form\controllers\IndexController.php**

```
public function postAction()
        {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $model = Mage::getModel(form/form)->setData($data);

            try {
                $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
                echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
```

**app/code/local/Svi/Form/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Svi_Form>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Svi_Form>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <form>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Svi_Form</module>
                    <frontName>form</frontName>
                </args>
            </form>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <form>
                    <file>form.xml</file>
                </form>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <form>
                <class>Svi_Form_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>form_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </form>
            <form_mysql4>
                <class>Svi_Form_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <form>
                        <table>svi_form</table>
                    </form>
                </entities>
            </form_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <form_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Svi_Form</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </form_setup>
            <form_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </form_write>
            <form_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </form_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <form>
                <class>Svi_Form_Block</class>
            </form>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <form>
                <class>Svi_Form_Helper</class>
            </form>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Please show your config xml code?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$model = Mage::getModel(form/form)->setData($data);
```

with

```
$model = Mage::getModel('form/form')->setData($data);
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but How did you know that error. Can you tell me?

Comment: Static method getModel expects string value

Comment: Hey dude I have one another problem My table is blank but it gave me message "successfully inserted". What to do?

Comment: It's very hard exactly answer on your question due a lot of possible answers. I'd recommend you to check your data array (which you get from $_POST). Then check what do you have inside $model->getData(). Compare table columns with your array $_POST values.

Answer (score 0):

There are may be few issue:

**Issue in model define:**

- May be  `model class(Svi_Form_Model_Mysql4) of your module is not define properly`  as you    want to save data in model.
- Check `resource model(Svi_Form_Model_Mysql4`) is define
  properly or not.
- Check `complier is enable or not.If yes then need to recompile`

**Basically, you does to put model pattern string  in single quote**

(`form/form') from`  (form/form)`