# how to save value of post data to a custom table in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, json

Getting error

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function setData() on boolean in /home/company/lampstack-5.6.28-1/apps/kb/htdocs/app/code/local/Namespace/Manager/controllers/Service.php on line 2849

My function in `IndexController.php`

```
elseif ($service == "getPunchHistory") {
            $res = $ws_service->ws_getPunchHistory($custid,$intime,$outtime,$inlocation,$outlocation,$punchstatus,$create_at);
            echo $_GET["callback"] . json_encode($res);
        }
```

my function in Included file in `IndexController` via another file. where my function is

```
public function ws_getPunchHistory($custid,$intime,$outtime,$inlocation,$outlocation,$punchstatus,$create_at)
     {
       if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        }
        else{
            $res["error"] = "Invalid request";
            return $res;
        }
        $res = array();
        $data = array();
        $custid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
        if ($custid != '')
        {
            // $collection = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->getCollection()
            // $data = $model->getData();
            try{
                $data = array(
                    'manager_id' => $custid,
                    'punch_in_time' => $intime,
                    'punch_out_time' => $outtime,
                    'in_coordinates' => $inlocation,
                    'out_coordinates' => $outlocation,
                    'status' => $punchstatus,
                    'create_at' => $create_at

                );
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
                $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_tracker';
               $smodel = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->setData($post_data)->save();  **// here is error line**

                $res['code'] = 200;
                $res['asmtracker'] = 'ok';               
            }catch(exception $exception){
                $res['code'] = 400;
                $res['asmtrakcer'] = $exception->getMessage();
            }

        }else{
            $res['code'] = 500;
            //$res['asmtrakcer'] = $exception->getMessage();
        }
        return $res;
     }
```

Comment: May be it will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120273/21339

Comment: may be your issue http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76707/45103